# Problems with responsive image 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am a student and working on a school project. I'm working on a responsive grid with 3 columns whenever u resize the widow the image should stay at 100% and only be visible once.

I came into an error with it, when full screen it takes up the full width but when i resize the widow the section overlay each other and only come back to full width (like they are supposed to be at phone size, mediaquery)

code snippet:

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
}
.columns {
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    height:100vh;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #92d2fc;
    background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=460%C3%97800&w=460&h=800);
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #fad74e;
    background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=460%C3%97800&w=460&h=800);
}
.red {
    background-color: #f88888;
    background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=460%C3%97800&w=460&h=800);
}
.blue img, .red img, .yellow img {
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .columns {
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
<section class="columns blue">
<h3>About us</h3>
<p class="margin-top">How the gym became a reality</p> 
</section>    

<section class="columns yellow">
<h3>Manifesto</h3>
<p class="margin-top">Respect the rules</p> 
</section>           
    
<section class="columns red">
<h3>Contact us</h3>
<p class="margin-top">Have a chat with us</p> 
</section>      
    
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!
Distortion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but it sounds like your problem is the fixed-width of the background image? Try something like `background-size: contain;` in your `.columns` class, or giving the background-size some percentage values.

Comment: That single line of code fixed my problem, thank you dear sir!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, this is what you are after. I make benefit of the `100vw` and `100vh` values.

> **vh** 1/100th of the height of the viewport.
>  
>   **vw** 1/100th of the width of the viewport.

Read more [about length at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Together with the `display: flex;` property ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)) it comes in handy to get the whole space filled out.

> The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox, is a layout mode providing for the
>   arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave
>   predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen
>   sizes and different display devices.

Also, I started *mobile first*, so that the `min-width` is set to `700px`, instead of the other way around. In that way you can scale easily to any size you want. You can also use `calc(value)` function to get 1/3th of the `width` of your screen width ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/calc)). In that case, replace the `width: 33.3%;` with `width: calc(100% / 3);`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.columns {
  width: 100%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #92d2fc;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #fad74e;
}

.red {
  background-color: #f88888;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {

  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }

  .columns {
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">

    <section class="columns blue">
      <h3>About us</h3>
      <p class="margin-top">How the gym became a reality</p>
    </section>

    <section class="columns yellow">
      <h3>Manifesto</h3>
      <p class="margin-top">Respect the rules</p>
    </section>

    <section class="columns red">
      <h3>Contact us</h3>
      <p class="margin-top">Have a chat with us</p>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I upadated your media query and added a `class="clearfix"` to your container

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
}
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }

.columns {
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    height:100vh;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px){
.blue {
    background-color: #92d2fc;
    background-image: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/jaysi/jaysi1112/jaysi111200023/11753777-Golden-temple-near-beautiful-lake-Japan-Vertical-image-Stock-Photo.jpg);
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #fad74e;
    background-image: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/jaysi/jaysi1112/jaysi111200023/11753777-Golden-temple-near-beautiful-lake-Japan-Vertical-image-Stock-Photo.jpg);
}
.red {
    background-color: #f88888;
    background-image: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/jaysi/jaysi1112/jaysi111200023/11753777-Golden-temple-near-beautiful-lake-Japan-Vertical-image-Stock-Photo.jpg);
}
  }
.blue img, .red img, .yellow img {
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .columns {
    width:100%;
    }
  .container{
      background-image: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/jaysi/jaysi1112/jaysi111200023/11753777-Golden-temple-near-beautiful-lake-Japan-Vertical-image-Stock-Photo.jpg);
      background-size:cover;
    height:auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
    
<section class="columns blue">
<h3>About us</h3>
<p class="margin-top">How the gym became a reality</p> 
</section>    

<section class="columns yellow">
<h3>Manifesto</h3>
<p class="margin-top">Respect the rules</p> 
</section>           
    
<section class="columns red">
<h3>Contact us</h3>
<p class="margin-top">Have a chat with us</p> 
</section>      
    
</div>
```